# Filter dictionary values by strings in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary, filter

Lets say I have a csv file which looks like this:

```
animal; breed; Owner; furcolor; name
dog; poodle; Steve; black; Olga 1
dog; poodle; Steve; black; Olga 2
dog; poodle; Steve; ; Olga 3
dog; poodle; Steve; brown; Paul 1
dog; poodle; Steve; ; Paul 2
dog; poodle; Steve; brown; Paul 3
dog; poodle; Steve; ; Paul 4
dog; poodle; Steve; brown; Paul 5
```

Now, I want to filter all entries, which don't have a value in the furcolor column. As a result, I should get the following two entries:

- dog; poodle; Steve; ; Olga 3
- dog; poodle; Steve; ; Paul 2
- dog; poodle; Steve; ; Paul 4

As all dogs named Paul [n] have the value 'brown' and all dogs named Olga [n] as their assigned fur color, I want my program to compare the beginning of the string of the owner name entry (In this case Paul or Olga) of my two filtered entries with all existing entries of the input file and assign the correct values to my filtered entries. As a result, I should get this:

- dog; poodle; Steve; black; Olga 3
- dog; poodle; Steve; brown; Paul 2
- dog; poodle; Steve; brown; Paul 4

In the last step, I want to add those completed entries to another csv file.

My current approach looks like this, but thats all I got so far:

```
import csv

with open(file.csv, 'r') as csvfile:
 reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=';')

 for row in reader:
     if row['furcolor'] == '':
```

Is there a way of doing this? I appreciate every help that I can get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure there is. Hope this helps, I've tried to be liberal with comments.

```
import io, csv, sys

# Inlined data for ease of reproduction. Could be a file handle.
csvfile = io.StringIO(
    """
animal;breed;Owner;furcolor;name
dog;poodle;Steve;black;Olga 1
dog;poodle;Steve;black;Olga 2
dog;poodle;Steve;;Olga 3
dog;poodle;Steve;brown;Paul 1
dog;poodle;Steve;;Paul 2
dog;poodle;Steve;brown;Paul 3
dog;poodle;Steve;;Paul 4
dog;poodle;Steve;brown;Paul 5
""".strip()
)

# Read in all entries.
entries = list(csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=";"))

# Compute a dictionary mapping the first word of the "name" to a fur color
# for each row that has a fur color.
name_to_color = {
    row["name"].split()[0]: row["furcolor"]
    for row in entries
    if row["furcolor"]
}

# Loop over all entries; fix up those with no fur color.
for row in entries:
    if not row["furcolor"]:
        name_prefix = row["name"].split()[0]
        # This line will crash if there is no matching fur color, and that's ok.
        row["furcolor"] = name_to_color[name_prefix]

# Write the entries back out (to stdout, but could be any other stream).
writer = csv.DictWriter(
    sys.stdout, ["animal", "breed", "Owner", "furcolor", "name"]
)
writer.writeheader()
writer.writerows(entries)
```

The output is

```
animal,breed,Owner,furcolor,name
dog,poodle,Steve,black,Olga 1
dog,poodle,Steve,black,Olga 2
dog,poodle,Steve,black,Olga 3
dog,poodle,Steve,brown,Paul 1
dog,poodle,Steve,brown,Paul 2
dog,poodle,Steve,brown,Paul 3
dog,poodle,Steve,brown,Paul 4
dog,poodle,Steve,brown,Paul 5
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot for your answer. As I am still a beginner in python (and programming in general),  I will take some time to understand the code and apply it to my problem.